# Assignement with parantheses in closure in d3 source code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While looking through the d3 source code, I [found this snippet](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/src/sequential.js#L47):

```js
  scale.unknown = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (unknown = _, scale) : unknown;
  };
```

This implements the pattern here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/. Here's a minimal example that works, with the above code adapted:

```js
function closure() {
  let mult

  function my(t) {
    return t * mult
  }

  my.mult = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (mult = _, my) : mult
  }

  return my
}
```

Afterwards, you can use it like this:

```js
fn = closure()
fn.mult(2)
console.log(fn(3)) // 6
fn.mult(4)
console.log(fn(3)) // 12
```

What I don't understand in my above example is this line:

```js
return arguments.length ? (mult = _, my) : mult
```

This checks if there are arguments, and assigns the parameter to mult if there are, or returns mult if there aren't.

But what does the parentheses mean in `(mult = _, my)`? What does putting the returned function at the very end do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have actually two different questions here.

The first one is about the parenthesis: Bostock (D3 creator) did that to take advantage of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which he commonly uses in his codes. In short, this...

```
return arguments.length ? (mult = _, my) : mult
```

Translates to: *does the function has any passed argument? If **no**, return the value of `mult`; if **yes**, return the `my` function AND assign the passed parameter to `mult`.*

Then you have a second question:

> What does putting the returned function at the very end do?

Not much, because that's not necessary. The test of `argument.length` is just to use a getter, that is, returning the stored value if no argument is passed. It could be just:

```
return arguments.length ? mult = _ : mult;
```

You can check this here:

```js
function closure() {
  let mult

  function my(t) {
    return t * mult
  }

  my.mult = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? mult = _ : mult;
  }

  return my
}

fn = closure()
fn.mult(2)
console.log(fn(3))
fn.mult(4)
console.log(fn(3))
console.log("stored value: " + fn.mult())
```